# Two Google Analytics Datas Differ in User & Session

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I'm currently running a website written by `Wordpress`: amninogym.com.

I'm using two google analytics property: `UA-147275396-2` and `UA-147275396-3` (deleted `UA-147275396-1` by the way).

`UA-147275396-2` is connected to the plugin named 'ExactMetrics' which is 'Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP)'.

`UA-147275396-3` is connected to Google Tag Manager.

What is weird is that the User & Session counts for these two differs.

Roughly, `UA-147275396-2` reports twice of Users & Sessions counts than those of `UA-147275396-3`.

I tried to find whether I hardcoded the snippet of `UA-147275396-2`, but I was not able to find any.

Please teach me how to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: These GA keys are critical data you'd better not to post them here . it's better to remove them if security matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possibilities for this:

1. The plugin is is not working correctly and sending duplicate data
2. GTM is not installed on all pages thus GA property firing from GTM is not capturing all users.

I tried to visit your site but it was not loading. Is it live?

Comment: Yes, it is! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Every time I go to amninogym.com it says: This site can’t be reached